# Smallest Ideal containing $a$ in commutative ring without unity

Tags: ring-theory

Let  $R$ be a commutative ring without unity such that $a$ belongs to $R$. Describe the smallest ideal containing $a$.

We know that in a commutative ring with unity $(a) = ${$r.a$ | $r$ belongs to $R$} but what is the case without unity.
I think $(a)$ = {$r.a+ n.a$ | $r$ in $R$ and $n$ belongs to integers}
but how would we prove this if it is correct.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The path is clear: you show the set you describe is an ideal, and then you explain n why every ideal containing $a$ must contain your set. All of this follows from axiom checking.

Comment: but i face problem in applying ideal test

Comment: @Yogi well, you ought to say that in your question AND tell us what step is causing you problems. I'll gladly expand my answer to address that but you have to throw me a bone here. I have no idea what trouble you're having.